# C++, constexpr и инициализатор синглтона

Tags: c++, constexpr, конструктор

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Singleton
{
    public:
    static const Singleton& instance()
    {
        const static Singleton singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

    private:
    constexpr Singleton()
    {
        fillTable();
    }

    constexpr void fillTable()
    {
        uint64_t value = 0;
        for (auto& element : table)
        {
            element = value;
            value = value * 2 + 1;
        }
    }

    // Копирование и перемещение запретили.
    // ...

    array<uint64_t, 1024> table;
};
```

Действительно ли такой код заполняет таблицу синглтона на этапе компиляции?

Если да, то что происходит при вызове конструктора? Ничего? То есть, таблица уже заполнена еще до вызова конструктора?

Comment: член не константное выражение,   функция выполняет инициализацию этого члена, значит неконстантное выражение, конструктор не может быть константным выражением, если вызывает эту функцию.... Непонятен ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Вычисления на этапе компиляции будут гарантированы только в том случае, если:

1. вычисленное значение используется в качестве параметра шаблона
   (*старый стиль*)
2. вычисленное значение записывается в `constexpr` -
   переменную. В остальных случаях - как повезет.

По вашему коду сделать вывод невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

1. На `constexpr-конструкторы` есть ограничения: все нестатические
   члены класса должны быть инициализированы **в списке
   инициализатора** конструктора(или при объявлении), точно также, как
   и обычно инициализируются константные члены класса. Поэтому вы не
   сможете вызвать constexpr_функцию в теле constexpr-конструктора для
   инициализации члена `table`.
2. Вы имеете возможность создать всего один экземпляр класса_одиночки
   посредством вызова статического члена, который возвращает
   статический обьект, поэтому   смысла нет содержать 
   нестатический член в этом классе.

Выражение `constexpr void fillTable()` означает, что функция ничего не возвращает, и это ничего является константным выражением. Одним словом `constexpr_функция` **должна возвращать значение**, являющимся результатом любого константного выражения.
Надеюсь я смог помочь понять, почему `gbg` прав в том, что

> По вашему коду сделать вывод невозможно